# How can I access Google Firestore from a Java client as a user (not admin)?

Tags: java, firebase, security, google-cloud-firestore, admin

I want to connect to Firestore and perform queries from a Java client. The client gets run by somebody who is a user of the Firebase application, not an admin. I have the user's JWT in a string. What I do not know is how -- and using which libraries -- I can
connect to Firestore.

What I tried:

- Package from Maven: implementation group: 'com.google.cloud', name: 'google-cloud-firestore', version: '2.6.1'

  - This package seems to be intended for usage on a secured server that has admin permissions, e.g. using a service account. I could not find a way to use it with a user account.
- Package from Maven: implementation group: 'com.google.firebase', name: 'firebase-firestore', version: '23.0.3'

  - This package is intended for Android and pulls in a load of Android-specific dependencies.

Why I think this is possible:

- Javascript code running on the browser can use the corresponding Javascript library to do exactly what I want (except being a Java library), using the "firebase" NPM package
- The Android-specific library is described as what I want (except the android part) -- though I did not know how to test this assumption

Why I want to do this:

- giving a user admin permissions instead is a violation of the principle of least privilege
- setting up a server between the client application and Firebase that runs on admin privileges does not serve any obvious purpose; it is not needed for a Javascript-based client either and would introduce a whole layer of potential security issues since any bug in that layer runs with admin privileges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no client-side Java SDK for Firebase/Firestore. The only SDK Firebase provides for such access is an Admin SDK, which (as you say) provides privileged, administrative access.

If you want to access Firestore with client credentials from non-Android Java code, you will have to [access Firestore through its REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/use-rest-api) [passing the user's ID token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/use-rest-api#authentication_and_authorization) (as opposed to an OAuth2 token) to ensure the security rules are enforced.

Comment: Thanks for the information -- good to know there is a REST API, and for other readers: Behind that link a gRPC API gets mentioned, which may be interesting too. WRT the credentials needed, which kind of token gets used by the Javascript Firebase client? I'm asking this because that token gets used in my Java application. On the outside, both a normal Firebase user's token as well as the identity token from "gcloud auth print-identity-token" seems to be JWT, but I guess that is only a container format that could be anything inside.

Comment: Update: I tried to understand the difference between the token from "gcloud auth print-identity-token" and the one the Firebase web client sends to Firestore, but it seems that both of them are OpenID Connect JWTs (having several fields that match the OIDC registered claims). Since OIDC tokens are OAuth2 tokens, it seems that the Javascript client *can* access Firestore with OAuth2 tokens. Is the REST API different in that respect, and if so, what kind of "user's ID token" is needed there?

Comment: The REST API *can* indeed use an OAuth2 token, but that'll grant you administrative access - which is what you're trying to prevent. To get access as a regular user, you should use their ID token, same as the Firebase Authentication client-side SDKs do.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification -- I was thinking that the ID tokens used by regular users were OAuth2 tokens too, because they are JWTs and the claims contained in them look like the well-known claims from OIDC.